How to mask values in "POST"/"PUT" request bodies and "Insert"/"Update" SQL statements in Sentry?

The request body of POST/PUT requests is being logged in Sentry, displaying the values. Instead, the log should show the keys and mask the values by replacing them with ** or ??.

The queries are logging the input values of INSERT/UPDATE SQL commands. The query should mask the values in the INSERT or UPDATE statements by replacing them with ** or ??.


PS. I am using nest.js for API where I want to mask the values.


